# Is there a better classical latin translation of don't let the bastards get you down?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Apologies for beating a dead horse but would any of these options grammatically make sense or work for 'don't let the 'jerks' grind you down' as bastard wasn't a thing apparently? I know nothis is an option but id like something that's an insult in classical latin?

```
Non te irrumatores terere
```

or

```
 Ne te irrumatores conterere
```

or

```
Noli sinere irrumatores te conterere
```

or

```
Noli irrumatores permittere te terere
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen [this earlier question on the phrase](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4592/79) and read its answers? That might give you ideas if not answers, and you can edit your question to update it if you have new insights.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is indeed interesting and Weimer's *Ne terant te spurii* seems excellent to me.

As a general thought, *ne* + *conj. pf.* is often an elegant solution for the so-called negative imperative: *Ne te triverint spurii*, e.g.

Comment: Hi! This is a good answer, but the question was closed as a duplicate. Would you mind reposting this as an answer to [the still open question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4592/79)?